# c# Segmenting a string and turning results into variables

Tags: c#, networking

Im trying to send a string of different variables combined together to a different server using sockets.

However i use ',' to split the data up. like this:

```
string stringToSend = (connectionType + "," + ownerID + "," + currentIP + "," + connectionOS); 
SendString(stringToSend);
```

so the data that is going to be received from the server is like:

```
"normal,user1,192.168.0.10,windows 10"
```

However I want to turn these strings back into variables on the other server. 
Im just a little unsure how to do this as the length of each variable is going to be different every time a string is sent to the server therefore I can't simply add numbers of where to remove data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're looking at making your own message protocol I would *strongly* suggest you do something more robust.  Would converting an object to JSON or Xml and back again not suffice?

Comment: Does your first line even compile?

Comment: Im just trying to send information about one client to a server. pretty knew at this, what would be the advantage of converting the object to JSON or Xml @Archer

Comment: One thing to think of is what if one of the variables had, in itself, a comma. Then one of your variables has been broken, and the index of everything after it is off.

Comment: It's safer if it's a serialized object as the data you send will be sanitized and hold more information than just the data (field names etc.).  Just imagine how your current code would react if Microsoft put a comma in the next OS version name.  There's a lot of possible flaws with something so simple, but the situation *may* suit it.  It's just worth thinking about the unknown possibilities.

Comment: @St.Pat Did consider that, however before the data is added in the variable it is appended to remove any commas to assure that there aren't going to be any in the string i send other than for a break line.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yeah I just wrote that out wrong my bad! Corrected now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could serialize with JSON and deserialize with JSON, on the receiver? Then you don't have to do any extra work, just import the JSON serializer.

That is what I would do.

Comment: I don't understand why I am being downvoted for the accepted solution? Please let me know what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you can use split:

```
 string[] a="normal,user1,192.168.0.10,windows 10".Split(',');

// a[0]= "normal"
// a[1]= "user1"
// a[2]= "192.168.0.10"
// a[3]= "windows 10"
```

Comment: Small note, but the argument given to Split should be single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: @st.pat the Split function accept char and strings.

Comment: the overrides include string arrays, but not a single string. https://dotnetfiddle.net/6UNSHf